# displaying list of powers program

Tags: java, math

I really need help with creating a program that displays a list of powers

here is the input and the output:

Input to the application is to include numbers to represent the following:

base
exponent (between 1 and 10)

Output is to list the number that you entered as a base and find the powers for that base from 1 up to the ending exponent number that is input.

I'm almost done the program, but the problem is that the program only calculate the base to the power without listing a list of powers.

I know i'm missing something in my loop
here is my code

```
double baseIn, exponentIn;

baseIn = Integer.parseInt(txtBase.getText());
exponentIn = Integer.parseInt(txtExponent.getText());
 //  power = (int) Math.pow(baseIn, exponentIn);

for (int i = 1; i <= exponentIn; i++) {
    txtArea.setText(Integer.toString((int) baseIn)+ "to the power of " + i + "=" + Math.pow(baseIn, i) );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem could be that you overwrite the test string of the output text area in each iteration of the loop, so that at the end -- probably without seeing anything else, because your code happens so fast that no repaint occured -- you, only see the last output.

Use a stringbuilder, append the string of each iteration, and only display the combined result after the loop.

Or use the already existing functionality

```
textArea.append(text + newline);
```

see for instance [Java Swing: Approach for dynamically appending text in text area, have scrollbar update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/983498/3088138)

Comment: Perfect!, I got exactly what i wanted , I used append instead of  setText as u mentioned  and got the correct output , thanks a lot LutzL
 I really appreciate it , 
so from what i understand u could use append when you out multiple integers out of loop?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. "append" keeps the existing text in the text area and adds the new text to it. This is all in strings, textarea does not know anything about integers. To reset the text area, you have to use "settext" once before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a recursive solution. Explained in steps. Assuming you want 2^4

1) we call power(2,4)

2) power(2,4) calls power(2,3)

3) power(2,3) calls power(2,2)

4) power(2,2) calls power(2,1)

5) power(2,1) calls power(2,0)

6) power(2,0) returns 1

7) power(2,1) returns (2 * 1) or 2

8) power(2,2) returns (2 * 2) or 4

9) power(2,3) returns (2 * 4) or 8

10) power(2,4) returns (2 * 8) or 16

```
public static int power(int base, int power){

     if (power == 0)

          return 1;

     else

          return base * power(base, power-1);

}
```

Comment: thank you for replying streamingBits , but to be honest i dont really understand your code, are you using classes, because im not really used to it, i'm still beginner in java

Comment: @issac no I am not using any other classes. Just this method. It is called recursion. It can be tricky to understand at first. It is a method that calls itself. I suggest reading into it online, even on stackoverflow. If I find a good resource I will get back to you.